# Can't add a php code to functions.php file

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to hide certain elements of the wpadminbar if you're not an admin but are logged in.

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can(administrator)){  

        #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo{display: none;}

         #wp-admin-bar-site-name{display: none;}
}
?>
```

I tried adding this code to the last line of functions.php file. The error I get is:

> "Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 533(which is the first line of the code) of file wp-content/themes/vtube/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.
>
> syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file"

Comment: Please supply the code.

Comment: `functions.php` ostensibly already has the `<?php` sequence earlier in the file; why are you trying to include another one? `unexpected '<'` should tip you off to this fact.

Comment: Further - how exactly did you come up with this code, and what, in plain English, do you expect it to do? `#` is an alternative syntax for indicating comments, which don't affect your code's functionality whatsoever. Even if both of your `if` conditions were met, this code is 100% inert and would not have any effect on your underlying site.

Comment: oh ok, so it will work if i start with "if". Sorry, as I said, I am just a beginner.

Comment: If you're "*just a beginner*" it may not be wise to modify your site's underlying PHP unless you know *exactly* what you're doing - while the code you have here is rather harmless (as I mentioned earlier) you can risk much worse (introducing severe security vulnerabilities, full-out irreparably breaking your site/database, etc....) when copy/pasting code from untrusted third-party sources. Until you have enough experience to decipher what a particular snippet does in practice, I would recommend staying away from these types of modifications.

Comment: Sure, but I still want to learn something; can I not add css within php like this? The "#" is supposed to be for denoting id as I want certain elements to be hidden if the user is not administrator. If the code won't work, can you spare some time and tell me how I can acheive this?

Comment: You should start from very beginning such as w3schools.com or something similar by search for "_php tutorial for beginners_". You can't just use CSS selector '#' like that in PHP. Start from something easy and simple like create/read/update/delete process.

Comment: @Patrick2997 "*can I not add css within php like this?*" Certainly not; can you link the source you're basing this implicit claim on...?

Comment: Not claiming anything. I'll use your advice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You do realize that hiding things via CSS only hides them **visually**.  It looks like you are modifying a theme's functions.php. The correct procedure is to create a child theme and add your own functions.php file.

Comment: Hiding with CSS doesn’t stop a user finding how to get those bars visible. You would need to instead stop the system outputting those bars in the first place so that would be in the code that creates the page. This absolutely must be done in a child theme, not the original themes code.

Answer (score 0):

If recommend you hide the entire thing for non-admins and your own component to show the things you do want them to see.

Code for hiding the admin bar for non-admins (I use this code myself, but seem to remember I've borrowed it from an answer on Stackoverflow so don't credit me for this):

```
function prefix_hide_admin_bar( $show ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( "administrator" ) ) {
      return false;
    }

    return $show;
  }
add_filter( "show_admin_bar", "prefix_hide_admin_bar" );
```

Answer (score -1):

First off, you shouldn't be modifying functions.php. A WP update could overwrite your changes.

You should put this in a plugin and when your if() condition is met, include a CSS file with the changes you want. There's documentation on including styles in the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) and you might have to tweak your CSS to get what you want.